# CakePHP support for initial configuration / web app installation?

Tags: cakephp, initialization, installation

I've got a CakePHP based web app that needs some initial configuration. I'd like to do the equivalent of the mysql source command to set up a bunch of tables / initial rows, then execute a $this->User->save() command to create the root account (I think this needs to be done via code since it'll use the salt value for the local install of CakePHP, which might/should be different than the one on my dev machine), etc, etc.

My hack-y solution is to expose a public method on a controller that does this, direct my browser to it, then set stuff up (via the Configure::load and Configure::dump) so that the route from that URL to the method is removed after the installation is complete.

Does CakePHP provide any support for 'installing' a web app?

Part of my problem is that my attempts at Googling for "CakePHP web app installation" are all overshadowed by the various tutorials (etc) about how to install CakePHP itself.  My issue is not installing CakePHP, it's providing an easy and safe way to set up the stuff my web app needs (like SQL database tables, etc) for it's particular needs.

Comment: Croogo (open source cakephp cms) does this.  Might look at how they do it:  https://github.com/croogo/croogo   It's not "built-in" to Cake, but it can certainly be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called Cake Schemas....

The simplest thing you can do in your development environment is run the following via command line from root:

```
./app/Console/cake schema dump --write filename.sql
```

Which gives you a dump of your SQL file then you can edit the sql file directly before using it.

You specifically ask for running `$this->User->save()`, while learning about Schemas might be a bit complicated, you can accomplish this by running

```
./app/Console/cake schema generate
```

Which creates your schema.php, then:

```
App::uses('User', 'Model');
public function after($event = array()) {
    if (isset($event['create'])) {
        switch ($event['create']) {
            case 'users':
                App::uses('ClassRegistry', 'Utility');
                $user = ClassRegistry::init('User');
                $user->create();
                $user->save(
                    array('User' =>
                        array(
                            'username' => 'admin',
                            'role' => 'admin',
                            'password' => 'admin'
                )));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Which makes a definition as you wish, then when you run:

```
./app/Console/cake schema create
```

Your tables get dropped, but remade as per your schema definitions and your model files, and with your specific "after" function

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/schema-management-and-migrations.html

Comment: Thanks a ton for the tip - this looks really useful (and Google-able)!

It looks like this is CLI-only, yes?  There's no way/intention of running this from a controller action?

Comment: Also - do you really need to MD5 hash the password yourself?  I've got a 'beforeSave' filter on the User model which does that for me.  (If I didn't need to have CakePHP do that for me then I'd just stick that into the SQL file, too).

Comment: You know what, you're right, I didn't consider that. I'll update my answer. I'll be honest I haven't tried running CLI on a production server, I've only played with this stuff on my dev stuff, but I don't see why this should be an issue, I've seen questions on here talking about running the cake console via a cron job ....

Comment: You could set up a custom controller that has no model, then make a view for said controller. When you install the program, access the view so that the controller runs, then delete the files for the controller and the view in case someone else access it. That's a bit of a hack way of doing it though.